# How to use contextMenuStripto remove linklable

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have created linklables dynamically and now i want to remove any of them by right clicking on that perticular linklable. I have tried it using context menu strip but i was unable to remove any linklable. Please help me on this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try handling the MouseDown event and getting the LinkLabel from the sender argument to the event handler? From there you should be able to remove it from its parent's Controls collection.

If you want to have the ContextMenuStrip for user interaction, you can still handle the MouseDown event of the LinkLabel and store the last clicked instance in the Tag property of the ContextMenuStrip. Then, when your menu item is clicked you can retrieve the last clicked LinkLabel and proceed to remove it from the controls collection.

```
private void removeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lbl = this.contextMenuStrip1.Tag as LinkLabel;
    if (lbl != null)
        lbl.Parent.Controls.Remove(lbl);
}

private void linkLabel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.contextMenuStrip1.Tag = sender;
}
```

Comment: i have tried with the code you have provided but now toolStripmenu is not appearing on linklable :)  Should i add toolstripmenuitem when i am creating a linklable?

Comment: That was just a template for how you could go about doing it. Since you are creating your LinkLabel controls at runtime, you'll also need to add the event handlers at runtime.

Comment: Also, you need to set the ContextMenuStrip property of each LinkLabel to the instance of your ContextMenuStrip you added to the designer.